# templatized global structure in c++

Tags: c++, templates, global-variables

i have a global structure

```
template <class FLOAT>
struct Cstruct {
    FLOAT var1;
    FLOAT var2;
};
```

FLOAT can be "double" or "int"

i want to declare a global Cstruct object but i do not know if it will be "double" or "int" at the time of compilation. is there a way to achive this ? thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you plan on using it?

Comment: the gloabl Cstruct will hold some data (double or int kind) which will eventually if used by other object memeber functions. it is lot of data. eventually i will be using it for a cuda program where i need to define the data in global memory for my specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the type of the template at the time of compilation.

If you need to figure out the type at runtime, then I would suggest just having each attribute be a `boost::variant<int, double>` instead.

Comment: is there a other way out without using boost or any other libraries. i want a plain c++ or c solution.

Answer (score 0):

One sort of insane approach is to make your entire program into a large `template`.

In this large `template<class Float> struct Program { ... };`, you use `static` methods for functions.

At run time, when you may know if your program is using a `double` or a `float` (I hope!), you figure that out, then execute that version of `Program`'s `static void main()`, the primary entry point of your `template`d program.

Now, not everything can exist within this `Program` `template`, as you can do different things within a class than outside of it: the point of the `Program` is to duplicate the main code flow and your "global state" in one spot.

`Program` can use other `template`s, like functions or traits or other similar collections of `static` data.  It can even call functions and do overload resolution based on the type involved.

If you can isolate what parts of your `Program` actually need to know what the `Float` is, this can save you much grief.  I'd only do this for a relatively simple program.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a union.  A union will allow the same memory to be used as either an int or a double.

```
union DoubleOrInt
{
    double dValue;
    int iValue;
};

struct Cstruct
{
    DoubleOrInt var1;
    DoubleOrInt var2;
};
```

Access the memory in Cstruct when you know the type it needs to be:

```
Cstruct Test;
Test.var1.iValue = 1;
Test.var2.dValue = 2.0;
```

Just note this this method will waste 4 bytes per union if you end up using integers instead of doubles (if your int and double variables have a standard size of 4 and 8 respectively).

Comment: this seems like a nice solution but in my original problem (i posted a simplified version) is where Cstruct.var1 and Cstruct.var1 in turn are templatized (double or int) structures.